# Android maps load markers from server dynamically

Tags: android, google-maps, client-server, google-maps-markers

I have integrated google maps to my app and I want to load markers dynamically. So here's what I did

- get bottom left and top right screen coordinates
- register `setOnCameraMoveListener` and override `onCameraMove` method where each time user scroll on map I send request to server with user screen coordinates
- server returns only those markers that are within user screen bounds (return as `json` object with marker id, lat, lng)
- check if newly downloaded marker id is present on map and if not add new marker on map

I wll add some code snippets here

```
mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraMove() {
                VisibleRegion vr = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
                LatLng top = vr.latLngBounds.northeast;
                LatLng bottom = vr.latLngBounds.southwest;

                String url = "http://192.168.137.1:3000/api/location/border?"
                        + "leftLongitude=" + bottom.longitude
                        + "&leftLatitude=" + bottom.latitude
                        + "&rightLongitude=" + top.longitude
                        + "&rightLatitude=" + top.latitude;

                downloader.sendGetToServer(url);
            }
        });

public void sendGetToServer(String url) {
        AndroidNetworking.get(url)
                .setPriority(Priority.LOW)
                .build()
                .getAsString(new StringRequestListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        if(listener != null && response != null && response.length() > 0) {
                            listener.downloadComplete(response);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ANError anError) {
                        Log.e("Error", anError.getMessage());
                    }
                });
    }
```

@Override

```
public void downloadComplete(String string) {
    try {
        Collection<MarkerItemData> mapMarkers = algorithm.getItems(); // get all markers from the map
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(string);
        JSONArray respondArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("respond");
        for(int i=0; i<respondArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject station = respondArray.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = station.getInt("_id");
            boolean skip = false;
            for(MarkerItemData markerItemData : mapMarkers) {
                if(markerItemData.getId() == id) {
                    skip = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!skip) {
                boolean criticalData = station.has("latitude") && station.has("longitude");
                if (criticalData) {
                    double lat = station.getDouble("latitude");
                    double lng = station.getDouble("longitude");
                    MarkerItemData offsetItem = new MarkerItemData(id, lat, lng, 1, "");
                    mClusterManager.addItem(offsetItem);
                }
            }

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So I'm wondering is there are any other ideas? I don't think that this approach is the best. First of all web request would me made even if user move map just a little bit. Also if I download lots of markers my app would be very slow. There are other apps like PlugShare that have implemented this behaviour with lots of markers.

Comment: You can try pattern B from [Google IO 2010 Virgil Dobjanschi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE).

Comment: GeoFire (https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js) seems like it would be good fit for what you're trying to do.....but does depend on data being stored in Firebase db.